# PayPal IPN payments

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I tried this script with Sandbox first time and ALL worked fine ! Now, I tried live version and I've got few errors: firstly was after payment because i wasn't redirect. But I saw how to solve it and now works fine . Second is : after payment i'm redirect to my IPN listener, but I don't know why I get invalid in Database even if I get money. This is my code. It's almost Paypal IPN from github. Do you have any idea ?

```
function get_item_price($item)
{
    $sqle = DB::conn()->query("SELECT cost FROM `paidservices` WHERE title LIKE '%$item%' LIMIT 1");
    $row1 = $sqle->fetch_assoc();
    return $row1['cost'];
}

function get_item_currency($item)
{
    $sqle = DB::conn()->query("SELECT currency FROM `paidservices` WHERE title LIKE '%$item%' LIMIT 1");
    $row1 = $sqle->fetch_assoc();
    return $row1['currency'];
}

function get_item_id($item)
{
    $sqle = DB::conn()->query("SELECT id FROM `paidservices` WHERE title LIKE '%$item%' LIMIT 1");
    $row1 = $sqle->fetch_assoc();
    return $row1['id'];
}

function get_item_amount($item)
{
    $sqle = DB::conn()->query("SELECT amount FROM `paidservices` WHERE title LIKE '%$item%' LIMIT 1");
    $row1 = $sqle->fetch_assoc();
    return $row1['amount'];
}

$run  = DB::conn()->query("SELECT * FROM `settings`");
$site = $run->fetch_assoc();
// CONFIG: Enable debug mode. This means we'll log requests into 'ipn.log' in the same directory.
// Especially useful if you encounter network errors or other intermittent problems with IPN (validation).
// Set this to 0 once you go live or don't require logging.
define("DEBUG", 0);
// Set to 0 once you're ready to go live
define("USE_SANDBOX", 0);
define("LOG_FILE", "./ipn.log");
// Read POST data
// reading posted data directly from $_POST causes serialization
// issues with array data in POST. Reading raw POST data from input stream instead.
$raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data);
$myPost = array();
foreach ($raw_post_array as $keyval) {
    $keyval = explode ('=', $keyval);
    if (count($keyval) == 2)
        $myPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
}
// read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc')) {
    $get_magic_quotes_exists = true;
}
foreach ($myPost as $key => $value) {
    if($get_magic_quotes_exists == true && get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1) {
        $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
    } else {
        $value = urlencode($value);
    }
    $req .= "&$key=$value";
}
// Post IPN data back to PayPal to validate the IPN data is genuine
// Without this step anyone can fake IPN data
if(USE_SANDBOX == true) {
    $paypal_url = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
} else {
    $paypal_url = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
}
$ch = curl_init($paypal_url);
if ($ch == FALSE) {
    return FALSE;
}
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
if(DEBUG == true) {
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, 1);
}
// CONFIG: Optional proxy configuration
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 1);
// Set TCP timeout to 30 seconds
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close'));
// CONFIG: Please download 'cacert.pem' from "http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html" and set the directory path
// of the certificate as shown below. Ensure the file is readable by the webserver.
// This is mandatory for some environments.
//$cert = __DIR__ . "./cacert.pem";
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, $cert);
$res = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch) != 0) // cURL error
    {
    if(DEBUG == true) { 
        error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "Can't connect to PayPal to validate IPN message: " . curl_error($ch) . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
    }
    curl_close($ch);
    exit;
} else {
        // Log the entire HTTP response if debug is switched on.
        if(DEBUG == true) {
            error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "HTTP request of validation request:". curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT) ." for IPN payload: $req" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
            error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "HTTP response of validation request: $res" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
        }
        curl_close($ch);
}
// Inspect IPN validation result and act accordingly
// Split response headers and payload, a better way for strcmp
$tokens = explode("\r\n\r\n", trim($res));
$res = trim(end($tokens));
if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {

    $item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
    $data = explode("-",$item_name);
    $item = $data[0];
    $itemID = get_item_id($item);
    $serverID = $data[1];
    $payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
    $payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
    $payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
    $txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
    $receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
    $payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];
    $time = time();
    $completed = "Successful";
    $paymail = $site['paypal'];
    $item_price = get_item_price($item);
    $item_currency = 'USD'; //get_item_currency($item);
    $item_amount = get_item_amount($item);
    $vipuntil = $time+$item_amount;
    if (($payment_status == 'Completed') && ($receiver_email == $paymail) && ($payment_amount == $item_price) && ($payment_currency == $item_currency)){
        $servicedb = DB::conn()->query("SELECT * FROM `paidservices` WHERE title LIKE '%$item%' LIMIT 1");
        $scount    = $servicedb->num_rows;
        if ($scount > 0) {
            $stmt = DB::conn()->prepare("INSERT INTO `payments` (serverid, serviceid, txnid, time, status, price, currency) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
            $stmt->bind_param("sssssis", $serverID, $itemID, $txn_id, $time, $completed, $payment_amount, $payment_currency);
            $stmt->execute();
            $st = DB::conn()->query("UPDATE `servers` SET vip='$itemID', vipuntil='$vipuntil' WHERE id='$serverID'");
            @session_start();
            $_SESSION['paypal'] = "YES";
            echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location = "/index"</script>';
        }
    } else {
        $invalid = "Invalid";
        $stmt = DB::conn()->prepare("INSERT INTO `payments` (serverid, serviceid, txnid, time, status, price, currency) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
        $stmt->bind_param("sssssis", $serverID, $itemID, $txn_id, $time, $invalid, $payment_amount, $payment_currency);
        $stmt->execute();
        @session_start();
        $_SESSION['paypal'] = "NO";
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location = "/index"</script>';
    }

    if(DEBUG == true) {
        error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "Verified IPN: $req ". PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
    }
} else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
    // log for manual investigation
    // Add business logic here which deals with invalid IPN messages
    if(DEBUG == true) {
        error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "Invalid IPN: $req" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case if you get an error regardin the database try to enable the DEBUG mode in this script ("DEBUG", 1) so that you can have a more precise error into the ifle ipn.log in your server. As it is a specific error would be helpful to know a little bit more of it.
Thanks, Andrea